# trouble querying has and belongs to many self join with rails activerecord

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to query an HABTM self join and can't seem to get the activerecord query right.

The goal is to have a couple major genres (rock, indie, jazz ....), and have sub-genres that map to them (ie. "rock" => ["rock&roll", "hard rock"... ]).  Then if we want to listen to the rock genre.  I'd like to find that genre and all it's sub-genres artists.

The model:

```
    class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_and_belongs_to_many :artists

     has_and_belongs_to_many :parent_genres, class_name: "Genre", foreign_key: "sub_genre_id", join_table: "parent_genres_sub_genres", association_foreign_key: "parent_genre_id"
     has_and_belongs_to_many :sub_genres, class_name: "Genre", foreign_key: "parent_genre_id", join_table: "parent_genres_sub_genres", association_foreign_key: "sub_genre_id"
    end


    create_table "parent_genres_sub_genres", id: false, force: true do |t|
        t.integer "parent_genre_id"
        t.integer "sub_genre_id"
    end
```

Now the real question:  How do I get a list of sub-genres for a bunch of genres?

I can query a single genres sub-genres. I know that `Genre.find_by(name: 'rock').sub_genres` returns this sql and the expected result of that genres sub-genres.

```
      Genre Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "genres".* FROM "genres" INNER JOIN "parent_genres_sub_genres" ON "genres"."id" = "parent_genres_sub_genres"."sub_genre_id" WHERE "parent_genres_sub_genres"."parent_genre_id" = $1  [["parent_genre_id", 13]]
```

I'd like to say something like, "Get me all of the subgenres for the user specified genres (rock, rap, indie, hip hop)?  But I can't seem to get the SQL right.  I think I need some kind of join, but any help would be appreciated.

So in the example below.  I could say get me Rock and all it's subgenres and get these ID's back [1, 7, 8] by saying `Genre.find_by(name: 'rock').sub_genres` or `Genre.find(1).sub_genres`

```
    Genre
    ---------
    id| name
    ---------
    1 | rock
    2 | indie
    3 | soul
    4 | house
    5 | indie pop
    6 | pop
    7 | stoner rock
    8 | indie rock

    Parent-Sub
    ---------
       sub_genre_id | parent_genre_id
    7 (stoner rock) | 1 (rock)
    8 (indie rock)  | 1 (rock)
    8 (indie rock)  | 2 (indie)
    5 (indie pop)   | 2 (indie)
    5 (indie pop)   | 6 (pop)
```

But how would I get back all the sub genres for Rock, Pop, and Indie at the same time? (which would be [1, 2, 6, 5, 7, 8])

Comment: `SHOW CREATE`, sample data, and example of wanted output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
class Genre < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :artists

 has_many :sub_genres, class_name: "Genre", foreign_key: "parent_id"
 scope :parents, -> { where(parent_id: null) }
end
```

This will allow you to do:

```
@roots = Genre.parents

@roots.each do |parent|
   parent.sub_genres.each do |sub_genre|
       puts sub_genre.id
   end
end
```

Your use of a HABTM association is, IMO, not required, as the genres are self referential

---

**Ancestry**

I would *highly* recommend using the [`ancestry` gem](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) for this

This gives you a framework which does exactly what you need (provide parent / sub records). I can detail more about how to use this gem if you require (we've recently got it working with categories)